# Why does Gnome-Shell act differently on my desktop than my laptop?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Another question today; I have gnome-shell installed on both my laptop and my desktop, but on my desktop it acts *entirely different* then if it is on my laptop.

I know that sounds weird, so here is a description:

On my laptop, Gnome-Shell is used through a menu (accessed using the windows button on my keyboard, or an on-screen button) which lists all my open applications and workspaces. I prefer this version greatly.

On my desktop, though, Gnome-Shell acts nothing like this. Instead, the top of the screen lists applications and places. Through applications I can access, obviously, the different applications, and through places I access the home folder and the like.

These two enviroments are entirely different, yet both go under the moniker "Gnome-Shell". How is this, and how do I convert my desktop to the laptop format of gnome-shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your desktop may have entered fallback mode. It's not the actual gnome-shell. Can you tell me the specs of your desktop. You'll enter enter fallback mode if you haven't got the appropriate drivers for your video card. Or if your hardware simply can't support the shell.

Comment: This may be related; I finally switched from fglrx to the open-source drivers for my computer to get dual monitors working. I actually haven't tested gnome-shell now that im on open-source. But here are my specs anyway: MSI ATI Radeon5670. Hopefully, good enough to run gnome-shell. :3

Comment: That'll get gnome-shell running. Tell me the results after using the open source drivers.

Comment: Yes, got gnome-shell running. Thanks for the help :) I was just too quick to ask the question, I guess, but I'll mark this as the correct answer because it is the correct answer :)